# What do they want to know, when they ask 'what's she like'?

Tags: meaning

> **What’s she like**?
>  She’s shy, but she’s very kind.
>  (From a Korean middle school English textbook.)

‘*What* is used to ask for particular information about somebody/something’ says [Oxford](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/what).
 When they ask about a person like the example, what do they want to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two such inquiries we commonly make about people, *Who is she?* and *What is she like?*

***Who is she?*** asks about a person's social role—depending on context, family or occupation or position within a community or organization. It elicits answers like:

- She's Bob's older sister, married to the Seibold boy.
- She's the head of the graduate program in English. Specializes in Victorian lit.
- She's something in marketing.

***What's she like?*** asks about personal qualities and behavior—what should I expect in my interactions with her.

- She's a lot of fun—plays your typical blonde, but very sharp underneath. And very reliable: if she says she'll do something, she does it.
- Pure poison. A manipulative, self-seeking back-stabber.
- Very demanding, very tough, but maybe the best teacher I ever had.

Answer (score 1):

**What's she like?**

This question usually asks for personality,behavior,temperament and psychological qualities of a person. But when you ask this question:

**What does she look like?**

It refers to visual specialties like appearance and physical characteristics.

The first question is more general than the second one. For example if you ask:

What's Korea like?

You want to know about people,culture,weather,nature,landscapes and architecture all.